# React Router v4 HOC with render props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to pass a props and declare a HOC in my route for authentification

Currently, I use

`<Route exact path="/add" component={requireAuth(Add)} />`

and it is working but without props.

I believe to pass a props you need to use the render syntax like this

```
<Route exact path="/add" render={props => <Add {...props} type="MyProp" />}/>
```

But is there any way to pass a HOC here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can . assign a capitalized variable to  `requireAuth(Add)` .

```
const AuthAdd = requireAuth(Add);
<Route
  exact
  path="/add"
  render={props => <AuthAdd {...props} type="MyProp" />}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter).

```
<Route exact path="/add" component={withRouter(Add)} />
```

Inside your `Add` class you will then be able to access the router props.